# Move Amazon Button on Woocommerce Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to move the Amazon Pay message/button on the checkout page in Woocommerce. We are using [Amazon Pay by Woocommerce](https://woocommerce.com/products/pay-with-amazon/).

When I look at the plugin code I have determined that in the plugin's file /woocommerce-gateway-amazon-payments-advanced.php the message/button gets added using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array( $this, 'checkout_message' ), 5 );
```

If I change 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form' to 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form' it moves. I have been struggling to figure out how to hook into the plugin from my functions.php.

Comment: Did you mean it doesn't move?

Comment: Nope. It moves, I just can't figure out how to hook into it from my functions.php.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
function move_amazon_pay() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', array( wc_apa(), 'checkout_message' ), 5 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', array( wc_apa(), 'checkout_message' ), 5 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'move_amazon_pay', 11 );
```

`woocommerce_checkout_init` must be at priority `11`, because the Amazon Pay plugin adds the action at priority `10`.

Use `wc_apa()` instead of `$this` because `wc_apa()` returns an instance of the `WC_Amazon_Payments_Advanced` class, allowing you to access the `checkout_message` method.